# What is the pythonic way of slicing an array into stepped contiguous blocks?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have an array/list/string, e.g. `arr=[0,1,2,3,...,97,98,99]`

How do I slice it such that the output are contiguous chunks stepped by a certain amount, e.g.:

```
out = [0,1,10,11,20,21..]
```

I've tried variations on `out = arr[(0,1)::10]` but to no avail. Am I missing something really simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: which type are you interested in? `numpy` arrays allow extended indexing while python built-ins (i.e. `list`, `tuple`, `str` etc) do not.

If you want a solution that works for any one-dimensional sequence, then simply use:

```
from itertools import chain

result = list(chain.from_iterable(seq[i:i+step] for i in range(0, len(seq), step2))
```

In your case you want `step` to be `2` and `step2` to be `10`.

In any case for generic sequences you *must* do one slice for each consecutive portion you want to select, so I don't think you can do much better than this.

For `numpy` arrays you could `reshape` the array into a multidimensional array such that the continuguous parts are all at the start of a row and select the first portions of the rows:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: seq = np.array(range(100))

In [3]: seq2 = seq.reshape((10, 10))

In [4]: seq2[:, :2]
Out[4]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [10, 11],
       [20, 21],
       [30, 31],
       [40, 41],
       [50, 51],
       [60, 61],
       [70, 71],
       [80, 81],
       [90, 91]])

In [5]: seq2[:, :2].reshape((2*10,))
Out[5]: 
array([ 0,  1, 10, 11, 20, 21, 30, 31, 40, 41, 50, 51, 60, 61, 70, 71, 80,
       81, 90, 91])
```

(There are many ways to reshape and flatten the result; read the `numpy` documentation if you are interested).

Note however that this will fail if the slices overlap, while the first solution works (repeating some elements, but that's what should happen).

---

If you don't care for overlapping slices (i.e. slices never overlap), then you can simply do:

```
indices = frozenset(range(step))
result = [el for i, el in enumerate(seq) if i % step2 in indices]
```

This may seem more efficient than doing multiple slicing, but I wouldn't be that sure because here you need an indexing operation per element instead of one per slice. Especially in CPython this may not be more efficient than the first solution especially if `step` is big.

---

From this last idea you could also do something to avoid `reshape`ing the numpy array:

```
indices = frozenset(range(step))
arr = np.array(i % step2 in indices for i in range(len(seq)))
result = seq[arr]
```

However I cannot think of a simple and efficient way of building the `arr` array of indices, so I doubt it improves performance.